# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElementsByTagName' in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to display a simple chart, and I am importing the following files (I'm using Highcharts 3.0.7):

```
highcharts.js
data.js
exporting.js
```

I am trying to draw a chart based on a table. This is the table:

```
<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Jane</th>
            <th>John</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Apples</th>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Pears</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Plums</th>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Bananas</th>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Oranges</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
$(function() {
  return $("#container").highcharts({
    data: {
      table: $("#datatable")
    },
    chart: {
      type: "column"
    },
    title: {
      text: "Data extracted from a HTML table in the page"
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false,
      title: {
        text: "Units"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

As you can see, it's almost the same as the example found here:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed

However, I'm getting the following error from `data.js`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElementsByTagName'
```

No bars are displayed, but the canvas is drawn. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Maybe wait for the document to load?

Comment: I've waited and nothing changes

Comment: No, I mean wrap the code in a `document.onload = function()`

Comment: It's wrapped in a jQuery(document).ready statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your codes from

```
data: {
  table: $("#datatable")
},
```

to

```
data: {
  table: document.getElementById('datatable')
},
```

<kbd>[Fiddler Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/kL9nu/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

change your codes to,**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zF2rc/)**

```
    data: {
        table: $('#datatable')[0]
    },
```